# Embedding corpus with BERT (as well saving the vocab) without using pretrained BERT

Tags: embedding, corpus, pre-trained-model

Like word2vec / GloVe, I wish to **embed my domain specific corpus** (around 10M words) with **BERT from scratch**. With these embedding, I may use them for sentence similarity (already used SBERT). But I do not want to use any **pretrained models/data** (fine tuned models for classification/next sentence prediction).

So far, I was unable to find any solutions/approaches to embedding (own) corpus with BERT other than the ones used here: https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_classifier.py

Is there any possible way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem are already addressed in the following issue:
https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/615

Also to generate the domain specific vocabulary refer this repo https://github.com/kwonmha/bert-vocab-builder

Hope it helps!